# Find number of product with different url for different store

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have a website which has two stores fr and en. Now I have almost 1500 products and we would like to add language switching in it. we did it but issue is that most of the product have same URL key for both stores, which are working fine. Some of them have different url for different stores. For them I have added URl rewriting in admin.

Is there a way to find number of product which have different URL for different stores. So  ot will be easy for me to add url rewriting for them.

--
Cheers

Comment: which Magento version & flavor you are using?

Comment: I am working on old site that is build on magento 1.6.1